# iOS Picker with year optional

Tags: ios, ios7, uidatepicker

I need to mount a UIDatePicker where the year is optional as in the picture.

[image]

is it possible?

Comment: Not possible with `UIDatePicker`. Create your own with `UIPickerView`. BTW - what `NSDate` value would you use for the date with no year?

Comment: you can make your own date picker, is little work but if you must it you can do it is not too much work :)